# security salt explanation

Tags: security

What does salt do and what is it for?

Does it provide additional characters so hashed values would be more unique?

Comment: This not really related to java or spring.

Comment: basically yes. http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: I mean the salt principle isn't related to java or spring, just to security.

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the tags

Answer (score 0):

When storing passwords in a database it is common to use a cryptographic hash function to store a hash value instead of storing the password. The idea is that storing the password directly would make it far too easy for anyone with access to the database to retrieve it. In theory, it is infeasible to reverse the hash (i.e. it is computationally complex) to tell what password created the hash value, but it is simple to generate the hash for a given password, thereby making it easy to confirm if a user has entered a matching password simply by matching the hash values.

For this process to work, the hashing function must return the same value every time. This is where salts become useful - let me explain:

**How hashing a password works**

Imagine you have two users - Alice and Bob.

Alice has the password 'mypassword'. When Alice enters her password, I calculate the SHA1 hash value for this password and store it my the database. The value is

```
SHA1('mypassword') = '91dfd9ddb4198affc5c194cd8ce6d338fde470e2'
```

Bob also has the password 'mypassword'. When I calculate and enter his hash value into my database, it will also be

```
SHA1('mypassword') = '91dfd9ddb4198affc5c194cd8ce6d338fde470e2'
```

Notice that both users will have the same hash stored in my database:

```
USER   HASH
Alice  91dfd9ddb4198affc5c194cd8ce6d338fde470e2
Bob    91dfd9ddb4198affc5c194cd8ce6d338fde470e2
```

I do not need to enter the actual password in my database because every time Alice or Bob tries to log in, I take their attempted password, apply the hash function to that attempted password and match the resulting hash value against my database. If the hash value matches the hash value in my database, I can let the user in. If the hash values do not match, I can reject the login attempt.

This is far better than storing 'mypassword' in the database because at first sight, someone who had access to my database can not easily tell what the password is. This is the benefit of a using a ***cryptographic hash function***. So far, salts or salting does not apply here.

But there are still two common problems with using our hash function here:

1. If Alice or some other attacker who knew Alice's password got into my database, it would be easy to see that the hash value for Alice and Bob is the same. She knows that her password is 'mypassword' and also that Bob's hash is the same as hers - this is enough to know that it is likely that Bob's password is also 'mypassword' and attempt to access his account.
2. Many attackers also use what is known as a 'rainbow table' or pre-calculated list of hash values to attack password systems. Suppose Carol want's to attack my system. She has gone through the dictionary and thought up some common passwords. Some of the passwords she has chosen are 'password' and 'mypassword'. She has applied the cryptographic hash function to these words before trying to attack my system. In her list she has entries that look like this:

   password = 5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8

   mypassword = 91dfd9ddb4198affc5c194cd8ce6d338fde470e2

If Carol gets access to my database, straight away she can match the hash value in the second entry to the hash values for Alice and Bob in my database. She now knows she can use 'mypassword' as their password and attempt to enter my system. Even worse, she may try and go and access other systems (such as Alice's email account) and check if she has the same password there. In reality, a rainbow table is usually a large file containing all alpha numeric combinations of characters (sometimes symbols) up to a certain length and the resulting hash value.

**Salts and Salting**

Salting aims to prevent the two issues above with very little extra effort.

When Alice and Bob change their password, I will now also generate a random two-character string that is known as a 'salt'.

For Alice, my random salt is going to be 'aa'.

For Bob, my random salt is going to be 'bb'.

Now when a user sets their password, I will add the salt to the end of the password before calculating the hash value. Therefore, when Alice sets her password I do the following:

```
SHA1('mypasswordaa') = 8bbf177f836204a63ee9032311da9be3a8528fb8
```

and when Bob sets his password I do the following:

```
SHA1('mypasswordbb') = d1958d2ce09379a32bcb651346f02f3a73819561
```

I store these new hash values and the salt in the database like this:

```
USER  SALT  HASH
Alice aa    8bbf177f836204a63ee9032311da9be3a8528fb8
Bob   bb    d1958d2ce09379a32bcb651346f02f3a73819561
```

It is still very easy for me to check if a user has entered the right password. When Alice logs in, all I need to do is look up her salt and add it to the end of her entered password before generating a new hash value. If that hash value matches, she has entered the right password.

But there is now a difference when considering the above two problems -

1. Even though Alice and Bob have the same password, you cannot tell from looking at my database. This protects against the first problem above.
2. The rainbow tables that Carol generated above no longer work. If Carol wants to generate hash values against my database she now needs to go back and generate every combination of password with every combination of the two character salt. This takes more time. I can further protect myself against this attack by placing a value between the password and salt (such as '+' or '&' or the username) or increasing the length of my salt strings.

While there is the possibility of a user getting my salt values directly from the database and then going away and using them to create their rainbow tables in the worst case this is no less secure that not using salts at all